# ld: library not found for -lgcc

Tags: homebrew, gcc

After a `brew upgrade` every time I try to compile a `.c` file I get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Wrappers like `mpicc` still work though. I tried relinking with `brew link --overwrite gcc`, but got no working results, as it is already linked. `brew doctor` doesn't give me a hint.

Comment: What is library gcc? What is the full line you are using to compile? .c files are compiled to .o and are not linked. Why use brew's gcc rather than Apple's clang?

Comment: @Mark, just compiling a simple Hello World program with `gcc -o helloworld helloworld.c` fails and shows that error.

Comment: Where is gcc i.e. what does `type -p gcc` show

Comment: It's in /usr/local/bin/gcc

Comment: See https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/40653 what version of Xcode do you have

Comment: @Mark, according to `brew doctor` I have Xcode 7.2. It suggests me to update it to version 7.3.1. Still, gcc worked until yesterday and this suggestion has some days old.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure with it's like this, but if I compile with `gcc-4.9` (as the gcc version I have instaled is version 4.9.2) instead of `gcc` it works as it should. So the compilation sentence that seems to work is `gcc-4.9 -o exec_name program.c`. If someone knows why it is like this I would be interested to know.